# How do I use Flyway in a continuous release process of a Java application?

Tags: flyway

I am new to Flyway. I like it a lot and I'm about to integrate it into our Java workspace. I need a little "push" however when planning the actual release procedure of these migrations. According to Flyway's documentation I have the choice of

- distributing a list of Sql files or
- distributing a list of both Sql and Java files packed into a jar archive.

I would like to try the second option because it gives us more flexibility and it sounds like I could simply include the migration scripts as resources in the jar file of the executable. However as we deliver database changes quite often in a continuous release process I see the jar file eventually being polluted with tons of script files. Moreover, when using Ant to create the jar file Ant will put the name of every file into the manifest's classpath which will make the manifest just messed up.

With these concerns in mind, for those of you that use Flyway in production:

What is the recommended way of distributing migration scripts? Do you put all of them into a jar and pass it to flyway on the server? Or do you copy all scripts to the server using a batch file everytime you make a release? Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

1. war project is built with maven
2. war project src/main/resources/db/migration has the migration scripts.
3. DB migration scripts are packages when the war is built.
4. When the war is deployed as part of container startup, db migration using flyway is executed.

The above approach is followed for local development environment, Test/Stage environment are continuously deployed by Jenkins pipeline and DB Migrations are automatically run.

In case of failures in Continuous deployment pipeline, we manually run db migration using flyway command line.

We also have the option of running flyway using command line for production deployment and for trouble shooting.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a jenkins job to automate flyway migration.You can do it in 2 ways.

1. By configuring the goals and options to run the

> compile flyway:migrate -Dflyway.user="xxxxx" ...(your other options)...

2. By installing a Flyway Runner Plugin on [Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Flyway+Runner+Plugin)

I would prefer doing it using the first option as you won't have to install anything on your Jenkins box.

Comment: I like the approach of delegating this task to the build server. However, wouldn't this require that the build server connects to the customers' servers and directly changes the customers' production databases (including rollout of the latest application code)? In my scenario the build server does only the build and testing and the delivery or rollout takes place later as a separate task.

Comment: So we use a separate job in our cert and prod domains for migration which migrates the DB and makes schema changes. This job is different from the normal Jenkins job that builds and rolls out the latest application code. We separated this because sometimes we may have to run the migration before we release the new jars into cert(or prod) and sometimes we will have to do it after the release, whichever way separation of responsibilities worked well for us so far. Hope this answers your question.